# Submitting the closest form without a submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have page with **many** forms consisting of only a `textarea` and a hidden field with an `id`

I am trying to use `jQuery` to submit the form each time the user enters some text and hits `command+enter` on the keyboard.

For that I am using

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.metaKey) {
```

That part works fine, but then when I try to submit my form the script stops execution. I am sure I am doing some mess with the `closest('form')` submit.

Here is my full code

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.metaKey) {
        $('textarea').closest('form').submit(function() {
        $.post("someurl.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
    };
});
```

When I debug it never enters inside the `$('textarea').closest('form').submit(function() {`

Any idea how can I pass the content of the form for which `command+enter` was entered to my `processing URL`?

Any tips will be appreciated, 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

HTML code for the forms

```
    <form action="#">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your answer"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="idval" value="xxxx">
    </div>
    </form>
```

**EDIT 2**

While debugging the code I see that the parameters are correctly passed but at one point jquery loses the values.

What is even stranger is that the fiddle posted below works fine in fiddle, but when I download the code and test it on my localhost it doesn't.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

  <title> by b</title>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.metaKey) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).closest("form").attr("action"), { html: $(this).closest("form").serialize()}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
}//]]> 

</script>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
<textarea name="area1"></textarea>
</form>

<form action="#">
<textarea name="area2"></textarea>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

any clues?

Comment: Look closer at `$('textarea').closest('form').submit(function() { ...`. This finds all `textarea` elements, gets the closest `form` for each one, and attaches a `submit` handler to each `form`. It does not trigger a `submit` event for anything.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK , Shouldn't the submit event be triggered when it gets to  `$.post()`?

Comment: If you are still having problems then adding your HTML markup would be helpful.

Comment: No, you would need to do `$('textarea').closest('form').submit()` to submit the form. You want to take the part where you are setting the submit handler, move that to be triggered once on document.ready, and then bind the keydown function to actually submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define an event handler inside another event handler. You should just post the current form.

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.metaKey) {
        $.post($(this).closest("form").attr("action"), $(this).closest("form").serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `$(this).serialize()` refer only to the `textarea` - not the whole `form`?

Comment: yes, when I try this it does execute the code, but I get the whole HTML of the page being submitted instead of only the current form elements.

Comment: I also tried this `$.post($(this).closest("form").attr("action"), $(this).closest("form").serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
    });` but still same result. It is still passing the whole HTML

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. I tried it in a fiddle and it only submitted one form at a time: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ywzmtvg6/1/

Comment: Thanks @barmar, I checked the fiddle and it does works fine, I really don't get it why it is not working on my code. I get the whole HTML from the `action` of the `form` I will keep debugging and come back for submitting your answer as right once I find out what is going on.

Comment: Hello @Barmar, I updated my question with some code. Your fiddle works perfectly, but when tested on localhost, I can't make it work. Do you see any logic explanation for that? Thanks a lot. Above is the code from your fiddle I am testing on localhost.

Comment: You don't have a URL in the `action` attribute, so there's no place for it to send the AJAX request when it sends to `$(this).closest("form").attr("action")`